# python pandas - unable to left join

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to left join the 2 tables below using merge. The main table is the following.

```
print(MbrKPI3.head())
```

[image]

The table to be left joined is below.

```
print(df5.head())
```

[image]

The below is the merge code, using primary key 'Loyalty Card No_'

```
MbrKPI4=pd.merge(MbrKPI3, df5,how='left',on='Loyalty Card No_')
```

But it does not work, with the below error. Can someone advise? Thanks!

```
KeyError: 'Loyalty Card No_'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with parameters `left_index` and `right_index`:

```
MbrKPI4=pd.merge(MbrKPI3, df5,how='left',left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

but also works [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), left join is by default:

```
MbrKPI4=MbrKPI3.join(df5)
```

Sample:

```
MbrKPI3 = pd.DataFrame({'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]},
                   index=[1,2,3])
MbrKPI3.index.name = 'Loyalty Card No_'
print (MbrKPI3)
                  B  C
Loyalty Card No_      
1                 4  7
2                 5  8
3                 6  9

df5 = pd.DataFrame({'E':[4,5,6]},
                   index=[1,2,3])

df5.index.name = 'Loyalty Card No_'
print (df5)
                  E
Loyalty Card No_   
1                 4
2                 5
3                 6
```

```
MbrKPI4=pd.merge(MbrKPI3, df5,how='left',left_index=True, right_index=True)
print (MbrKPI4)
                 B  C  E
Loyalty Card No_         
1                 4  7  4
2                 5  8  5
3                 6  9  6

MbrKPI4=MbrKPI3.join(df5)
print (MbrKPI4)
                 B  C  E
Loyalty Card No_         
1                 4  7  4
2                 5  8  5
3                 6  9  6
```

Comment: thanks for the reply jezrael, it works! do you know why can't I specify a column name (Loyalty card no) for both of them to join?

Comment: because it is not column, but index, check it `df5.index`